# How to let "file section" display on the left hand side of Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to search from `tools -> preference`, but can't find the answer.

Does anyone know how to make a **file section** display on the left hand side of Oracle SQL?

(As the highlight part in this picture)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the **View** menu. Click **Files** in that menu. That should be it.